# Topological properties and product product topology

Tags: general-topology, product-space

I wondering if you guys could help me figure out some stuff.
Let $(X,\tau_{1})$ and $(Y,\tau_{2})$ be  topological spaces.

I know that:

if  $(X\wedge Y)\in T_{0}\implies X\times Y \in T_{0}$

if  $(X\wedge Y)\in T_{1}\implies X\times Y \in T_{1}$

if  $(X\wedge Y)\in T_{2}\implies X\times Y \in T_{2}$

if  $(X\wedge Y)\in T_{3}\implies X\times Y \in T_{3}$

$T_{3}$ meaning that $\forall x \in X\quad \wedge\quad \forall A^{closed}\subset X \quad \exists W,V \text{  such that } W\cap V =\emptyset\quad $ and W and V are neighbourhoods for x and A.

I am wondering if the verse can also be said. That is if $X\times Y \in T_{i}\implies (X\wedge Y)\in T_{i}$?

In other words can we replace the implication with equivalence? And if not when can do that.

Thanks for any help

Edit:What about compactness and connectedness?

Comment: Consider the projection maps $p_X:X\times Y\to X$ and $p_Y:X\times Y\to Y$.

Comment: The projections need to be continuous so my question now becomes if these properties are keep when mapping them with a continuous function right?

Comment: You asked for the verse?  Are you expecting us to be topological poets?

Answer (score 1):

First remark: $X\land Y \in T_0$ makes no sense. You probably mean (if you really want to use symbolism for this at all): $(X\in T_0) \land (Y \in T_0)$ instead.

If $p \in X$, the subspace $\{p\} \times Y$ is homeomorphic to $Y$ and if $q \in Y$, $X \times \{q\}$ is homeomorphic to $X$.

And all these separation properties $T_0, \ldots T_3$ are hereditary.

Compactness and connectedness are preserved by continuous images so there use that $\pi_X[X \times Y] = X$ and projections are by definition continuous in the product topology.